# Calling an android function from a package "library"

Tags: java, android

I have several android applications where approx 80% of the code is the same so I put it in a package "library".  Eclipse seems to call this a library eventhough its a package and not like a class that I need to instantiate.  The unique bits (ie. lookup tables) to setup things are separate from the package.  This is working well and I can call package functions.  Is there a way to go backwards.  In each of my applications I want to have a function (ie foo() ) that does something different in each application.  I'd like to be able to call foo() from a function in the package.

Answer (score 1):

Consider everything as a library, even your main applications.

Then I think your situation is currently like this:

- `common-lib`
- `app1`, requires `common-lib`
- `app2`, requires `common-lib`
- `app3`, requires `common-lib`

And you now want `common-lib` to refer to code in `app1/2/3`? That isn't possible, but maybe you can accomplish that using [dependency injection](https://stackoverflow.com/q/130794/823470).

#### Dependency Injection

Make an interface in `common-lib` that defines the actions you need to invoke. Then create classes implementing that interface in `app1/2/3`. Finally, make `app1/2/3` pass an instance of their version of that interface to `common-lib`, so it can use it.

In `common-lib`:

```
interface Named {
  void getName();
}

class MasterOfCeremonies {
  static void introduce(Named guest) {
    System.out.println("Please welcome " + guest.getName());
  }
}
```

In `app1`:

```
public StudentJohn implements Named {
  void getName() {
    return "John";
  }
}
```

In `app2`:

```
public StudentMary implements Named {
  void getName() {
    return "Mary";
  }
}
```

This way, `app1` can then invoke `MasterOfCeremonies.introduce(new StudentJohn())`, and `app1` can then invoke `MasterOfCeremonies.introduce(new StudentMary())`, and `common-lib` will do different things for each of them.

#### Additional Note

I don't know your exact situation, but another thing that may be useful is making another even "more common" library, like this:

- `other-lib`
- `common-lib`, requires `other-lib`
- `app1`, requires `common-lib`
- `app2`, requires `common-lib`
- `app3`, requires `common-lib`